# Creating a force layout in D3.js visualisation library

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I'm working on a project, which visualises the references between books. It's worth to mention that I'm a total beginner in Javascript. So, I couldn't get far by reading the D3.js API reference. I used [this example code](http://bl.ocks.org/2949937), which works great.

The structure of my CSV file is like this:

```
source,target
"book 1","book 2"
"book 1","book 3"
```

etc.

The source and target are connected by a link. These are the points for the layout:

1. Create two different circles respectively for source and target node.
2. Set a specific color for source and target node.
3. The circles should be labeled by the book information, e.g., source node
   is labeled by "book 1" and target node is labeled by "book 2".
4. If there is a link between targets, then make this specific link wider
   than the others links from source to target.

I hope you can help me by creating these points.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards
Aeneas

Answer (score 1):

d3.js plays much nicer with json data files than with csv files, so I would recommend transferring your csv data into a json format somehow. I recently coded something similar to this, and I had my nodes and links stored in a json file as a dictionary formatted as such:

```
{ 
'links': [{'source': 1, 'target': 2, 'value': 0.3}, {...}, ...],
'nodes': [{'name': 'something', 'size': 2}, {...}, ...]
}
```

This allows you to initialize your nodes and links as follows (after starting the view):

```
d3.json("data/nodesandlinks.json", function(json) {
var force = self.force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(json.nodes)
    .links(json.links)
    .linkDistance(function(d) { return d.value; })
    .linkStrength(function(d) { return d.value; })
    .size([width, height])
    .start();

var link = vis.selectAll("line.link")
    .data(json.links)
    .enter().append("svg:line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("source", function(d) { return d.source; })
    .attr("target", function(d) { return d.target; })
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return d.value; });

var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(json.nodes)
    .enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("name", function(d) { return d.name; })
    .call(force.drag);
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: You can server json or use d3 to convert csv to json. d3 has some great tools for converting csv to json.  These two examples might help:

csv string to json - https://gist.github.com/3053667

csv file to json - https://gist.github.com/3053705

Then this page for further manipulating arrays: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays